# how to get column name on hql (like get metadata from resultset)

Tags: hibernate, metadata, hql

i want to get the name of columns into HQL query result (with unkwon query content & class "Student" attribut)

```
>     Query query = session.createQuery("from Student s ");
>     ScrollableResults list = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
>     
>       while (list.next()) {
>       
>           for(Object obj : list.get()){
>                   System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>: "+ obj);
>                   }
>                    
>           }
```

like this

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student");
      ResultSetMetaData md = resultSet.getMetaData();

            for (int i = 1; i <= md.getColumnCount(); i++)
                 System.out.print(md.getColumnLabel(i) + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `query.list()`. It will return a list of maps, a map per row. Each map would map column name to an object corresponding to the column value for the given row.

Read the first map, and its keyset would contain the names of the fields in the query result.

Comment: return this  key 0 => value : "xxxx"

Comment: @user2784559: Oops! You can try getting metadata about the Student class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576014/hibernate-query-metadata

Comment: the prob  we dont know the class because the query well be sent by xml ; we have only what the query return ("SELECT * FROM STUDENT") just example